# Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Tags: compiler-errors, android-instant-run

I have a trouble with this error
[image]

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I read some article, they said that I should enable/disable Instant Run. But this way doesn't work for me. Any recommend me?